# How to resolve does not exist on type 'HTMLTableDataCellElement' issue in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I used a  primeng p-table in angular

```
  <p-table        
      [value]="users"
      class="user-roles-table"
      [rows]="5"
      [showCurrentPageReport]="true" 
      [paginator]="true"
      currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries"
      [rowsPerPageOptions]=[5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,50]
      [globalFilterFields]="['fullNameForShow', '', 'status']"
      [alwaysShowPaginator]="false"
      #gridTable
    >
      <!--<p-table [value]="users" class="user-roles-table" [scrollable]="true"  scrollHeight="60vh"> -->
      <ng-template pTemplate="caption">
          <div class="p-d-flex">
              <span class="p-input-icon-left p-ml-auto">
                  <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
                  <input pInputText type="text" (input)="gridTable.filterGlobal($any($event.target).value, 'contains')" placeholder="Search keyword" />
              </span>
          </div>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
          <th pSortableColumn="fullNameForShow" style="width: 250px;">
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between p-ai-center">
              Name
              <p-sortIcon field="fullNameForShow"></p-sortIcon>
              <p-columnFilter
                type="text"
                field="fullNameForShow"
                display="menu"
              ></p-columnFilter>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th pSortableColumn="admin">
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between p-ai-center">
              Roles
              <p-sortIcon field="admin"></p-sortIcon>
              <p-columnFilter
                type="text"
                field="name"
                display="menu"
              ></p-columnFilter>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th pSortableColumn="status" style="width: 135px;">
            <div class="p-d-flex p-jc-between p-ai-center">
              Status
              <p-sortIcon field="status"></p-sortIcon>
              <p-columnFilter
                type="text"
                field="status"
                display="menu"
              ></p-columnFilter>
            </div>
          </th>
          <th style="width: 80px;">Action</th>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-user>
        <tr>
          <td>{{ user.fullNameForShow }}</td>
          <td  #myCell>
            <ng-container *ngIf="myCell.showAll">
              <p-chip
              *ngFor="let roleAndGroup of user.roles"
              styleClass="mr-2 mb-2"
              [label]="getRoleAndUserGroupName(roleAndGroup)"
              [removable]="true"
              (click)="onDelete(roleAndGroup)"
            ></p-chip>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="!myCell.showAll">
              <p-chip
              *ngFor="let roleAndGroup of user.roles | slice:0:3"
              styleClass="mr-2 mb-2"
              [label]="getRoleAndUserGroupName(roleAndGroup)"
              [removable]="true"
              (click)="onDelete(roleAndGroup)"
            ></p-chip>
            <p-chip
            styleClass="chipMore" (click)="myCell.showAll = !myCell.showAll"*ngIf="user.roles.length >= 3">+{{ user.roles.length - 3 }}</p-chip>
            </ng-container>
           
          </td>
          <td>
            <span
              [ngClass]="
                isUserActive(user.status)
                  ? 'status-active'
                  : 'status-inactive'
              "
              >{{ user.status }}</span
            >
          </td>
          <td>
            <div class="action-set">
              <p-button (click)="onAddRole(user)" pTooltip="New Role" tooltipPosition="top" class="newRoleBtn" [disabled]="false"></p-button>
              <span class="action-drop" #toggleButton (click)="toggleMenu()">
                  <ul *ngIf="isMenuOpen" #menu appendTo="body">
                      <li><a>Edit</a></li>
                      <li><a>Reset Password</a></li>
                      <li><a>Delete</a></li>
                      <li><a>Duplicate</a></li>
                      <li><a>Deactivate User</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </span>
            </div>
        </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </p-table>
```

after writing this code its throwing a error.

Property 'showAll' does not exist on type 'HTMLTableDataCellElement'.
<ng-container *ngIf="myCell.showAll">

Property 'showAll' does not exist on type 'HTMLTableDataCellElement'.
<ng-container *ngIf="!myCell.showAll">

Property 'showAll' does not exist on type 'HTMLTableDataCellElement'.
<p-chip styleClass="chipMore" (click)="myCell.showAll = !myCell.showAll"*ngIf="user.roles.length >= 3">+{{ user.roles.length - 3 }}

Please help me on these issue.
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you defined a property named "myCell" in your component's ts file?

Comment: @Yogi....tried defining in both ways...still its throwing same error  
 1)@ViewChild('myCell', { static: false }) myCell: any;
 2)public myCell:any;

Answer (score 0):

Your `myCell` is template reference of `td` html element which doesn't contain `showAll` property which error messages told.

I'm not sure about your goal but here is solutions.

**Solution 1**

Add optional mark to the property eg. `*ngIf="myCell?.showAll"`

**Solution 2**

Declare new property in component and replace showAll property of myCell eg. `*ngIf="toggleShowAll"`

**Solotion 3**

While you use PrimeNg, why not modify table's component to be `PrimeNg Row Expansion` [primeng doc](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/table/rowexpansion)